# error: bad operand types for binary operator '/'

Tags: java, arrays, types, operand

I have a program where the user inputs marks into the array and then gets the average value

My problem is that when I do the average method, it gives me an error which is

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '/'.
```

This is my code :

```
//averageEnglish
public void averageEnglish() {
    System.out.println("The Average Mark Of English Is");
    int averageEnglish = english / 10;

}//End of averageEnglish
```

English is an int array

```
int[]english = new int [10];
```

Comment: What's `english`? Is it something you would reasonably expect you could divide by 10? If it's a string, you'll need to parse it into some kind of number first.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing an array of numbers doesn't make any sense. You probably need to add the items in the array and then divide by the length.